# Problemas com CONVERT_TZ e BETWEEN no Mysql 5.1.73

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando fazer essa busca com `CONVERT_TZ` e `BETWEEN` no MySQL 5.1.73 mas sempre retorna zero linhas.

Alguém já usou `BETWEEN` dessa forma?

```
SELECT 
x.UserName, 
x.StartDate , 
x.EndDate 
FROM tabela AS x 
WHERE (x.UserName='usuario') AND
CONVERT_TZ('2014-02-25 18:27:30','+11:00','-03:00') BETWEEN x.StartDate AND x.EndDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz o seguinte exemplo e funcionou:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tabela (
    UserName varchar(100),
    StartDate datetime,
    EndDate datetime
  );

insert into tabela (UserName, StartDate, EndDate)
values
  ('eu', '2014-02-25 04:00:00', '2014-02-25 05:00:00'),
  ('me', '2014-02-25 03:30:00', '2014-02-25 04:30:00'),
  ('jo', '2014-02-25 03:00:00', '2014-02-25 04:00:00');

SELECT *
FROM tabela AS x 
WHERE CONVERT_TZ('2014-02-25 18:27:30','+11:00','-03:00') 
    BETWEEN x.StartDate AND x.EndDate
```

Note que a hora retornada pelo código:

```sql
CONVERT_TZ('2014-02-25 18:27:30','+11:00','-03:00')
```

É:

```sql
February, 25 2014 04:27:30+0000
```

### [Demo no sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3687d/5)

Provavelmente você não está obtendo o resultado porque:

1. As colunas `StartDate` e `EndDate` são do tipo `DATE` e não possuem informação de hora. Neste caso, você pode usar a função `date()` para remover o horário no momento da comparação.
2. Não há registros cuja data/hora retornada esteja dentro do intervalo. Talvez você estivesse esperando outro resultado.

Se seu caso for o do item #1, faça assim:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tabela AS x 
WHERE date(CONVERT_TZ('2014-02-25 18:27:30','+11:00','-03:00'))
    BETWEEN x.StartDate AND x.EndDate
```

### [Demo no sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ceb884/2)

Comment: Realmente eu tenho que pegar a data e a hora, meus campos estão como datetime...

vou testar esse aqui baseado no seu, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/8afd8/1

Comment: Ainda não funcionou, olha o exemplo que usei.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd4c1b/1/0

Comment: @AronPeyroteoCardoso O resultado está correto, é o caso do item #2 da minha resposta. Não tem nenhum intervalo que englobe o valor passado. Olhe esse [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd4c1b/7), eu procurei um a um e não tem nada.

Comment: @AronPeyroteoCardoso Agora, se você mudar a hora de `'2014-02-25 18:27:30'` para `'2014-02-25 18:27:27'`, aí você ontém um resultado, só para citar um exemplo.

Comment: Verdade, MUITO OBRIGADO.

Vou remover os segundos do campo de busca.